# tf.optimizer update all existed weights for sparse input

Tags: python, tensorflow, logistic-regression, tfrecord

I'm using tf to train a LR model via FTRLOp for sparse dataset. Code snippet as follows:

```
feature_columns = [
       tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket('query_id',15),
       tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket('ad_id',15),
       tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket('cat_id',15),
    ]
label_column = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('label', dtype=tf.float32, default_value=0)
columns = feature_columns + [label_column]
cols_to_vars = {}
parsed_example = tf.parse_example(serialized_example, tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(columns))
logits = tf.feature_column.linear_model(
            features=parsed_example,
            feature_columns=feature_columns,
            cols_to_vars=cols_to_vars
        )
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=label, logits=logits))
optimizer = tf.train.FtrlOptimizer(learning_rate=0.5, learning_rate_power=-0.5, initial_accumulator_value=0.5,  l1_regularization_strength=2, l2_regularization_strength=0.1)
```

trainables = tf.trainable_variables()
grads_and_vars = tf.gradients(loss, trainables)

The input is sparse and categorical, input is kinda one hot and memorize the nonzero indices, for example the first two records is:
    6, 10, 13
    3, 9, 12
The gradients shows:
    `The result of first record only input:
current gradients is: IndexedSlicesValue(values=array([[0.5]], dtype=float32), indices=array([6]), dense_shape=array([15,  1], dtype=int32))
current gradients is: IndexedSlicesValue(values=array([[0.5]], dtype=float32), indices=array([10]), dense_shape=array([15,  1], dtype=int32))
current gradients is: IndexedSlicesValue(values=array([[0.5]], dtype=float32), indices=array([13]), dense_shape=array([15,  1], dtype=int32))
current gradients is: [0.5]`

`Result of first two input:
current gradients is: IndexedSlicesValue(values=array([[0.25],
       [0.25]], dtype=float32), indices=array([6, 3]), dense_shape=array([15,  1], dtype=int32))
current gradients is: IndexedSlicesValue(values=array([[0.25],
       [0.25]], dtype=float32), indices=array([10,  9]), dense_shape=array([15,  1], dtype=int32))
current gradients is: IndexedSlicesValue(values=array([[0.25],
       [0.25]], dtype=float32), indices=array([13, 12]), dense_shape=array([15,  1], dtype=int32))
current gradients is: [0.5]`

Since the second record doesn't has value in 6, 10, 13, I don't think the gradients should change when finish processing the second. It seems not same as the computation in the Ftrl paper.

Any mistake pointed out ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

By far, I found at least one reason. The weights are updated via the the averaged gradients of each batch, which is nice for nn. Details here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/266968/how-does-minibatch-gradient-descent-update-the-weights-for-each-example-in-a-bat